# Editing folder customzise template windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to edit the folder template in the Customize tab (General items, Documents, Music etc) ?

Also how do I tell the Windows to apply the template in files that have images?

I want these template to apply to differently depend on what file is in the folder
ie: Auto change to Picture when there is image in the folder

I not looking to apply for all folder. Thank you